# Extremely odd behavior when running script

Tags: autohotkey

I'm not sure what to title this question because I don't even know what is going on. I'm getting something completely bizarre. The ahk program behaves nothing like I thought I programmed it. Here is my code. What happens is the program does a couple clicks and then starts spamming the click for 10-20ish seconds at incredible speed. Even though I have `Esc::ExitApp` I can't use it to exit the program. I just have to wait for the clicks to stop before I can use Esc.

Here is my code. I am pulling variables from vars.ahk. If you are wondering what the variables are, they are absolute coordinates to certain areas I would like to click on the screen. I will include both .ahk files in this question.

What could cause this behavior? The program has just simple clicks. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Thanks ahead of time!

**My.ahk**

```
#include C:\Users\user\Desktop\vars.ahk
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen

navigateToThing(){
    global nwmx, nwmy, dailyx, dailyy, specx, specy
    global ntmx, ntmy, safeclickx, safeclicky, dailyxx, dailyyy, nextx, nexty, okx, oky
    global gx1, gy1, gx2, gy2 ; green color window
    ToolTip, starting...
    Sleep, 700
    Click, left, %nwmx%, %nwmy%
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %specx%, %specy%
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %dailyx%, %daily%
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %ntmx%, %ntmy%
    Sleep 1000
    Click, left, %safeclickx%, %safeclicky%
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %dailyxx%, %dailyyy%
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %nextx%, %nexty%
    ToolTip
    ;InputBox, arbVal, , , , 100, 100 ; Wait for the okay
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, left, %okx%, %oky%
    
    Sleep, 5000

    Sleep 500
    Click, left, %backx%, %backy%
    Sleep 1000
    Click, left, %evox%, %evoy%
    Sleep 600
    Click, left, %evoxx%, %evoyy%
    Sleep 600
    Click, left, %safeclickx%, %safeclicky%
    Sleep 600
    Click, left, %dailyxx%, %dailyyy%
    Sleep 1000
    Click, left, %nextx%, %nexty%
    ToolTip
    ;InputBox, arbVal, , , , 100, 100 ; wait for the okay
    Sleep 1000
    Click, left, %okx%, %oky%
    
    Sleep, 5000
}
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
;MAIN
;----------------------------------------------------------------------

Sleep 1000
navigateToThing()

Esc::ExitApp
```

**vars.ahk**

```
specx = 1563
specy = 373

    dailyx = 956
    dailyy = 271
    ntmx = 1467
    ntmy = 406
    evox = 1787
    evoy = 649
    evoxx = 1256
    evoyy = 611
    safeclickx = 533
    safeclicky = 517
    dailyxx = 557
    dailyyy = 347
    nextx = 1234 
    nexty = 969
    okx = 981
    oky = 962

nwmx = 396
nwmy = 328

rumx = 948
rumy = 317

solox = 1281
soloy = 957

    gx1 = 1081
    gy1 = 995
    gx2 = 1168
    gy2 = 932
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `dailyy` here
`Click, left, %dailyx%, %daily%`.
So the command actually was
`Click, left, 956,` ,
which is interpreted as sending 956 left clicks.

Comment: Ohhh I see! Thank you! I switched away from AHK in the end :) Thanks though I appreciate this!